# Django multiple views one model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

i try to create something like subpages in User profile.

I try to create this because i think put everything(activity stream, user photos, wideo etc.) in one page it's not good idea.

I have multiple views with one model like:

```
def userprofile(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    context = locals()
    template = 'auth/user_detail.html'
    feeds = feed_manager.get_user_feed(user.id)
    activities = feeds.get('user')['results']
    activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
    user_from = len(Follow.objects.filter(user_from=user))
    target = len(Follow.objects.filter(target=user))
    current_user_following = Follow.objects.filter(user_from=request.user, target=user)
    args = {"user": user, "target": target,
            "current_user_following": current_user_following,
            "activities": activities}
    return render(request, template, args)

def userabout(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'auth/about.html',
                {'user': user})

def userphotos(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'auth/photos.html',
                {'user': user})
```

and on urls:

```
path('users/<username>/', views.userprofile, name='userdetail'),
path('users/<username>/about/', views.userabout, name='userabout'),
path('users/<username>/photos/', views.userphotos, name='userphotos'),
path('users/<username>/video/', views.uservideo, name='userphotos'),
```

When I type this link with username like: localhost:8000/account/users/Maciej/about/ then this works good. But i don't know how to link this in template.

I try `<a href="{% url 'userabout' %}">About me</a>` and then error apear "No reversMatch".

Im begginer, maybe there is a better option to do this? Or to link this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the username as an argument to the template tag. For example:

```
<a href="{% url 'userabout' user.username %}">About me</a>
```